# newlines also removed by splitting

Tags: python, string, list, split

I was trying to make a compression algorithm and a compressor that uses it in python.
While doing so, I saw that when compressing some example text, newlines are gone.
After some debugging, I found out that the `split()` function was removing the newlines.
I was converting a string to a list and a list to string so many times, but this time, the `split()` function removed all the newlines. If it would be a string:

```
i
hate foo
bar why do people use it what does it even mean
```

but after calling `split()`, it becomes:

```
['i', 'hate', 'foo', 'bar', 'why', 'do', 'people', 'use', 'it', 'what', 'does', 'it', 'even', 'mean']
```

Comment: And what do you actually intend to do?

Comment: That's what ``split`` is supposed to do. What result where you actually expecting? Do you want a flat list like ``['i\nhate', 'foo', ...``, or like ``['i\n', 'hate', 'foo', ...`` or something else?

Comment: @bool3max well, it's a compression algorithm (which likes to split strings and convert them back to lists), part of a bigger project (open-source) but will only be open-sourced when complete. that's what i intend to do.

Comment: I meant in this particular question, what did you expect to happen when you called `.split` on your input string? Because the behavior you observed is completely expected, yet you did not specify, in your question, what is wrong with it from your point of view.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I want the first one which you specified

Comment: @bool3max Well, I expected the newlines to stay there

Comment: Well, I have to wait 8 minutes before accepting @Daweo's answer but that works. EDIT: Accepted now

Comment: This behaviour is explained in the fine [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) of the `split()` method: "If *`sep`* is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split()` without argument given does split at any whitespaces, newline (`\n`) is one of whitespaces. If you want to split only at space characters, then provide `" "` as split 1st argument that is

```
text = '''i
hate foo
bar why do people use it what does it even mean'''
elements = text.split(" ")
print(elements)
```

output

```
['i\nhate', 'foo\nbar', 'why', 'do', 'people', 'use', 'it', 'what', 'does', 'it', 'even', 'mean']
```